# Set selected value on entity field (Symfony Forms)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm working with the [Sonata AdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/index.html) and I would like to set the **selected value** of my **select list**.

I have a **Category** with fields: `CategoryID, parentID, tag`. The parentID can be NULL.

The code how I build my form:

```
// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{        
    // If edit -> get tag and id from tag
    if($this->subject->getCategoryId() !== null)
    {
        $tag_current = $this->subject->getCategoryId()->getTag();
        $tag_current_id = $this->subject->getCategoryId()->getParentid()->getCategoryid();
    }

    $formMapper
        ->add('tag', 'text', array('label' => 'Tag'))
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Naam'))
        ->add('nameEN', 'text', array('label' => 'Naam Engels', 'required' => false, 'data' => 'test'))
        ->add('parentcategory', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'DX\MyBundle\Entity\Category',
            'empty_data'  => null,
            'empty_value' => "GEEN PARENT CATEGORIE",
            'required' => false,
            'data' => $tag_current_id,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($tag_current) {

                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where('c.parentid IS NULL')
                    ->andWhere('c.tag != :tag')
                    ->andWhere('c.tag != :tag_current')
                    ->setParameter('tag', 'FOTOGRAAF')
                    ->setParameter('tag_current', $tag_current);
            }
        ))
    ;
}
```

As you see I've tried to set **data property** with no result. The **empty value** `NO PARENT CATEGORY` is always selected on page load.

My `$tag_current_id` is an integer, in this case: `11` . And my select list looks like this:

```
<select id="s54ff22c20ca39_parentcategory" name="s54ff22c20ca39[parentcategory]" class="select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" title="Parentcategory">
    <option value="">GEEN PARENT CATEGORIE</option>
    <option value="1">THEMA</option>
    <option value="11">FREEM SELECTIE</option>
</select>
```

But still not selected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your query builder should return all the available values, it will select automatically your database value :

```
$formMapper->add('parentcategory', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'DX\MyBundle\Entity\Category',
    'empty_data'  => null,
    'empty_value' => "GEEN PARENT CATEGORIE",
    'required' => false,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                  ->where('c.parentid IS NULL')
                  ->andWhere('c.tag != :tag')
                  ->setParameter('tag', 'FOTOGRAAF')
    }
))
```

**Update:**

This is what i'm doing in my project :

```
$formMapper->add('supplier', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeCoreBundle:ShopSupplier',
    'empty_value' => 'None',
    'empty_data' => null,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('ss')
            ->orderBy('ss.name', 'ASC');
    }
))
```

It selects automatically the database value and set the empty_value when none is selected. If it doesn't work in your project, i have no idea.

Comment: Then he always selects the empty_value. And it's important that my category is not in the select list, that's why I have my second "andWhere"

Comment: In my case, 'empty_value' was the way to set the default value (without messing around with injection, id's index nor choices). Thanks dude!